# How to specialize call template in c++ operator()?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider this code:

```
struct PixelProcessChannelwise {
  template<class Op, typename... Args>
  void operator()(float *dest, int process_nchannels, Args... srcs) const {
    for (int ch = 0; ch < process_nchannels; ch++) {
      Op{}(dest, srcs[ch]...);
    }
  }
};

struct add1_op {
  void operator()(float& dst, float x) const {
    dst = x + 1;
  }
  typedef PixelProcessChannelwise processor;
};

void f() {
  float f = 1.0;
  auto pp = PixelProcessChannelwise();
  pp(f, 0, &f);
}
```

This doesn't compile because in `f()`, `pp` doesn't know which op to use. I tried `pp<add1_op>(&f, 0, f);` but clang says pp does not name a template. What's the right way to invoke `pp` operator() with a template arg? (I want it to be a template arg so it inlines rather than calling through a function pointer.) Or if this can't work, is there an efficient alternative to do what I'm after? I want to have various `PixelProcess*`, and `*_op` methods and mix them efficiently.

Comment: Any reason to not have the operation as a parameter to the function?  otherwise you need something like `pp.template operator()<some_type>(...)`

Comment: `pp.operator ()<add1_op>(&f, 0, &f);`; however, `add1_op` is not compatible with the template operator (would require `Op()(` **\*** `dest, srcs[ch]...);`).

Comment: Thanks for these comments -- it's hard to figure out that syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler would be to pass functor in argument:

```
struct PixelProcessChannelwise {
  template<class Op, typename... Args>
  void operator()(Op&& op, float &dest, int process_nchannels, Args... srcs) const {
    for (int ch = 0; ch != process_nchannels; ch++) {
      std::forward(op)(dest, srcs[ch]...);
    }
  }
};

struct add1_op {
  void operator()(float& dst, float x) const {
    dst = x + 1;
  }
  typedef PixelProcessChannelwise processor;
};

void f() {
    float f = 1.0f;
    auto pp = PixelProcessChannelwise();
    pp(add1_op{}, f, 0, &f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this would definitely be simpler -- but wouldn't this prevent inlining and force calling the op through the function pointer? (I'm not sure, just asking) That ch loop is my innermost loop so every cycle matters.

Comment: Also can you explain the std::forward and && -- how do they help in this case? I understand with data classes they prevent copies but this is a stateless functor.

Comment: You might get rid of `&&` and forwarding for simplicity. It might happen that the functor has different overload depending if it is rvalue or not, that's why I added it.

Comment: With type, compiler has all information for inlining (contrary to function pointer).